# How to switch one class version to another class version cache with Hazelcast without the load balancing url gets down?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hazelcast

I have a spring boot configuration for hazelcast to support 2 nodes cluster cache.if I want to deploy a new version of existing class without application gets down what should I do?

when the existing cache of a class version is different from the new class version it is throwing serial version UID mismatch exception.I tried to add a new group from node 1 it works partially, but when the second node stops for the deployment, application url gets down because hazelcast is not switching to different group cluster automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try using IdentifiedDataSerializable. you can then send a version of the class, and do some conditional serilization.

Comment: do you have any reference for this?

Comment: You can check the documentation: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Serialization/Overview.html